# 404 due to WordPress mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Client added a WordPress install to their document root directory.  Afterwards one non-WordPress directory is giving a 404.

In a browser you can access `/foo/facebook/index.php` with no issues but you get the WordPress 404 page if you try to access `/foo_admin/index.php`.  Wordpress is in / (not pictured here due to clutter).

Here is the entire .htaccess for the doc root directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

EDIT:

Just realized a basic auth .htaccess in /gcb_admin is interfering somehow.  Have now tried adding RewriteEngine off both before and after the basic auth directives but this changes nothing.  Removing basic auth directives allows access to file...

```
AuthUserFile /home/foof/.htpasswd
AuthName "FOO Admin"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET>
        require valid-user
</Limit>

RewriteEngine off
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: It is not clear where is the WP install or where is the .htaccess file, none of those directory trees seem to be WP. But, it looks like the `RewriteBase` path is not root and should be changed.

Comment: You are correct, per matthewpavkov I changed last line to `RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]` and that resolved issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution - essentially, it just turns off the rewrite engine in that specific directory:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-directories-from-wp-rewrite

Add a `.htaccess` file to the directory that you want the Wordpress rewrite to ignore, with this code:

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Or, try changing the last line you have to:

```
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Changing last line of WP RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]` resolved the issue.  Thank you!  Would you mind explaining what that syntax does?